# Probability and identical balls problem

Tags: probability

Suppose we have an urn with $2$ white and $2$ black balls then probability of drawing a black ball is $1/2$ .

In text books solutions to more difficult versions of this kind of ball problems are explained by naming black balls as $ b_1 b_2 ..$ and whites as $ w_1 w_2 .. $  etc..

***My question:***

These balls are identical, i.e blacks are identical in them and so does whites. Why do we name them as $b_1 b_2 ... w_1 w_2...$ is it a correct way to deal with problem how can an identical ball be numbered and thought that way ? How do you know which one you picked ? This confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In counting problems it plays a huge rôle whether the objects one is dealing with, or the actions one performs, are labeled or not. Stanley in his *Enumerative combinatorics*, Vol. 1, distinguishes **12 ways** to count maps $f:\ A\to B$, depending on whether $f$ is supposed to be arbitrary, injective, or surjective, and whether the elements of $A$, resp. $B$, are labeled or not.

If you want to derive some combinatorial formula for unlabeled objects it may helpful to label them anyway and then forget about the labeling in a second step. Consider the following example:

In how many ways can 3 red, 5 blue, and 2 yellow balls be arranged in a row? Label the red balls from 1 to 3, the blue balls from 1 to 5, and the yellow balls 1 and 2. Then we have 10 distinguishable balls which can be arranged in $10!$ ways. Now the 3 red balls among them can be arranged in $3!=6$ ways which cannot be distinguished when we rip of the labels, and similarly the blue balls can be arranged among them in $5!=120$ ways, the yellow balls in $2$ ways.
It follows that the total number $N$ of linear arrangements of the colored, but unlabeled balls is given by
$$N={10!\over 3!\cdot 5!\cdot 2!}=2520\ .$$

Comment: Isn't there an nicely illustrative subtlety here that you might have missed? `RRRBBBBBYY` and `YYBBBBBRRR` both contribute to your $N$. If you cannot make out the "direction" of the row (if the ends of the row aren't labelled `start` and `end`), you should count them as one.

Comment: @Gugg: I'd say that in such problems a "row" is directed if nothing is said to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

The labeling here is unimportant. The random variables for each color possess the property of being [exchangeable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable), roughly meaning that permuting their labels will not change the result.
If you permute $b_1$ and $b_2$, $w_1$ and $w_2$ (call $b_1$ by the label $b_2$ etc..., You will still end up with th same answer.

So basically, the labels here are only for mathematical convenience.

Answer (score 1):

If you wouldn't name or label identical balls, you wouldn't be able to count them: ball #1, ball #2, etc. But otherwise, what the other answer says.